# Appending HTML to polymer template root

Tags: polymer

I am unable to add dynamic HTML directly to a polymer element, but instead seemed to be forced to add it to an existing sub-element.  Is this a limitation of polymer, or just my lack of understanding?

While having yet-another-div is certainly popular, I was really hoping polymer would help me put that in my review mirror.

## Example

For the following element:

```
<polymer-element name="my-el1">
    <template>
      <div id='myid'></div>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

this script will only display when added to the div (#myid) and not the the template directly:

```
<script>
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML  = 'text';
this.appendChild(el);        //shows in DOM, not in browser
this.$.myid.appendChild(el); //works
</script>
```

## JSBIN

Full example at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tagaxotuve/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` references the Polymer object and not the actual DOM. In order to add something directly into the shadowDOM you need to use the following:

```
this.shadowRoot.appendChild(el);
```

Here is your JSBin: http://jsbin.com/lakijafexe/1/edit

Remember that shadowRoot is not a "tag" so you will see undefined for tagName for your example.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.  I think the shadowDOM light finally flickered all the way on.